# .gitignore is ignoring all files in subdirectories

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitignore

I added my composer vendor folder in gitignore using the lines below:

```
application/cache/*
public/uploads/*
application/config/credentials.php
application/logs/*
vendor/
.env
.DS_STORE
temp/
composer.lock
```

Thus it is excluding the vendor folder in the root of my application (same directory as `.gitignore` file)

However, it is also ignoring all files located at `/public/resources/member/js/vendor`.

How do I ensure that .gitignore only ignores the vendor folder at the root of the application ?

Comment: I think you need to prepend the path with `/`. `/vendor/`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+only+root

Answer (score 3):

You must change `vendor/` to `/vendor/` so git will ignore only the root vendor folder.